# Excel VBA code to clear data from one cell based on another cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm self taught and having an issue with something I thought would be easy.  I have a spreadsheet that i need to loop through column O and find any cell with data and clear contents of the corresponding cell in column H. The spread is sheet is ever changing so the last row of data is always changing.  Below is the code I have been playing with but can't seem to get to work.  Any help would be awesome..

```
    Dim deleterate As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

' set object
Set ws = Sheets("Import file")


' loop through the data to find the $$ amounts in column o

For deleterate = ws.Range("O" & Row.count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1

' indentify values in O which have value

If ws.Range("O" & deleterate).Value <> 0 Then
Cells(0, 7).ClearContents
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a row of `0`, so your line

```
Cells(0, 7).ClearContents
```

will give an error.  You should also always qualify which sheet you are referring to, unless you **know** you want to use the `ActiveSheet`.

---

So you should use

```
ws.Cells(deleterate, 8).ClearContents
```

to specify the correct row and column (because "H" is the 8th column, not the 7th) or even

```
ws.Cells(deleterate, "H").ClearContents
```

or, to be consistent with your previous line (the `If` statement), you could use

```
ws.Range("H" & deleterate).ClearContents
```

Comment: Thank you. That and adding a start position in the For statement fixed it.

Comment: @DennisHolt Ahh - I had overlooked that typo.  And, FWIW, it should be `ws.Rows.Count`, not just `Rows.Count`.  It will **usually** work without the `ws.`, but can lead to problems if you ever have multiple workbooks of differing Excel versions (e.g. `xls` and `xlsx`) open.